# Abrir Visual C++ com argumentos para compilar

Tags: c++, visual-studio

estou começando com o visual C++ e tenho um projeto onde é necessario o visual c++ compilar o programa automaticamente.
então pensei em argumentos como podemos usar no prompt normal como:

```
cmd /k cd c:/Windows
```

Mas não achei como fazer isso ja que o visual c++ é um atalho que ja usa esse preargumento /k. 
`%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat"" amd64_arm`

Pensei tambem em fazer um script .bat para abrir o visual c++ e compilar.

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools\vcbuildtools.bat"" amd64_arm;
cd C:\Users\Huron\Desktop\Injector\RandoInjector;
cl main.cpp;
```

E ele funciona só para abrir o visual c++.

Então estou nesse impasse alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o cl.exe que é o compilador de linha de comandos do Visual Studio. Inclusive nem precisa do Visual Studio, poderia usar apenas o build tools que já faria isso.

O primeiro passo é abrir o console usando um dos atalhos que ficam no Visual Studio no menu iniciar, lá você vai achar opções de 32 e 64 bits.

Uma ferramenta que pode considerar usar já que está querendo compilar fora do VS é usar o CMake.